# How to plot a graph from its adjacency matrix (coordinates manually specified)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, graphs

For example, I want to plot a graph whose [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is `[0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]`. I first plot three points labeled by `p1,p2,p3`, and link the points `p1,p2`, `p2,p3`. For a general case, how to link the points according to the adjacency matrix(which may be stored in a .txt file)?

Comment: To clarify: Are you choosing the coordinates for `p1,p2,p3` yourself, or do you expect that to be handled automatically?

Comment: Thanks! Choose the coordinates for `p1,p2,p3` oneself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, which uses Python to parse the adjacency matrix into something `TikZ` can read. I'm using a Mac, so take that into account when I declare my directories. The steps I'm showing are just an example, but I think that's better than to do it very abstractly. So suppose that your main `.tex` file is located in `/Users/Me/Desktop/latex/`.

**Step 1**: Create a file in `/Users/Me/Desktop/scripts/` called `adjmat.py` with the following contents:

```
F = file('/Users/Me/Desktop/latex/adjmat.txt','r')
L = map(lambda x: x.split(';'),F.readlines())[0]
L = [L[0][1:]] + L[1:-1] + [L[-1][:-1]]
F.close
S = ''
for i in range(len(L)):
    tempL = map(lambda x: x.split(','),[L[i]])[0]
    for j in range(i+1,len(tempL)):
        if tempL[j] == '1':
            S += '\\draw (p%g)--(p%g);\n'%(i+1,j+1)
G = file('/Users/Me/Desktop/latex/adjmat-tikz.txt','w')
G.write(S[:-1])
G.close
```

**Step 2**: Write your adjacency matrix to `/Users/Me/Desktop/latex/` called `adjmat.txt` with (for example) only the following text (the main thing is to have lines separated by `;` and cells by `,`):

```
[0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]
```

**Step 3**: In Terminal, run `python /Users/Me/Desktop/scripts/adjmat.py`.

**Step 4**: In your main `.tex` file, have the following `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (p1) at (0,0) {};
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (p2) at (1,0) {};
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (p3) at (1,1) {};
\input{adjmat-tikz.txt}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now you said that your vertices will be indicated manually, so that's what I worked with. I also assume they are named `p1`, `p2`, and so on. This generalizes to an adjacency matrix of any size, as long as there are no loops and no multiple edges. In this case, this is the result you get:

[image]

Comment: This is not really a TeX solution. If you are going to attack this problem with Python, I would at least recommend incorporating your scripts into the TeX document via PythonTex.

Comment: @mrc I thought of doing the parsing inside TeX, but as much as I've searched (which isn't too far) there's no clean, versatile text parser in TeX. It seems using [PythonTex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) would be similar to my approach, but longer - judging by the documentation, the `.tex` file has to be compiled, then a `.py` file has to be executed, and then the `.tex` file has to be compiled again. Although the Python script would then be inside the `.tex` file, I (personally) don't think that's better, because if another language must be used, why mix it up with `LaTeX`.