# How to plot a graph from its adjacency matrix and coordinates of vertices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, graphs, tikz-external

A similar question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164895/how-to-plot-a-graph-from-its-adjacency-matrix-coordinates-manually-specified). If we give all the data of the vertices's coordinates and the graph's adjacency matrix, how to plot it with tikz, pstrick or other tool in tex?

here are the data of adjacency matrix and coordinates

```
Coordinates:{{0.809,0.588},{0.309,0.951},{-0.309,0.951},{-0.809,0.588},{-1.,0.},{-0.809,-0.588},{-0.309,-0.951},{0.309,-0.951},{0.809,-0.588},{1.,0.}}

Adjacency matrix: {{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}}
```

Sometimes the number of data is too large to put the data in the main tex file. It would be better to import the data from external files. [Here is a large file of data](http://yun.baidu.com/s/1sjFdCD3).

Comment: What do you mean by "all the data of the vertices' coordinates"? It sounds like your looking at a specific matrix rather than an arbitrary matrix. The adjacency matrix is all that's needed to construct the graph.

Comment: Thanks! When we plot a graph, we plot each point according to its coordinate and then link them according to the adjacency matrix. So, coordinates of vertex are also needed.

Comment: Please post a sample of the adjacency matrix here and not in a link.

Comment: @PeterGrill The adjacency matrix is too large.

Comment: Then make it smaller. Make it a *minimal* working example.

Comment: @user25607 can I ask you how you are producing your data? Is it extracted from some program? Do you have control on its output?

Comment: @Bordaigorl The data is about the graph of 120-cell which is extracted from Mathematica.

Comment: @user25607 ok so I guess you can have very fine control on how this data is presented. Hence a simpler approach for the ext file problem is to generate valid tex code in the file from Mathematica and then simply `\input` it; for example, making your Mathematica output function write `\graphfromadj{p}{DATA}` in the file would make the use of catchfile unnecessary.

Comment: @Bordaigorl Yeah, you're right. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple solution requiring **only** TikZ

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,vertex/.style={draw,circle}, arc/.style={draw,thick,->}]
    \foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(0.809,0.588),(0.309,0.951),(-0.309,0.951),(-0.809,0.588),(-1.,0.),(-0.809,-0.588),(-0.309,-0.951),(0.309,-0.951),(0.809,-0.588),(1.,0.)}{
        \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
    }

    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
                \draw[arc] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This can obviously be wrapped into a macro accepting the adjacency matrix as argument.

The same idea could be used to generate the edges in a graph description parseable by the PGF3 graph library (requires LuaTeX).

Here's a "macroed" version handling the weighted case with customisable styles:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\graphfromadj}[3][arc/.try]{
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {#3}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
                \draw[arc/.try=\cell, #1] (#2\r) edge (#2\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\weigthgraphfromadj}[3][draw,->]{
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {#3}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \if0\cell%
            \else
                \draw[arc/.try=\cell, #1] (#2\r) edge node[arc label/.try=\cell]{\cell} (#2\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,
    vertex/.style={draw,circle},
    arc/.style={draw=blue!#10,thick,->},
    arc label/.style={fill=white, font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt}
    ]
    \foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(0.809,0.588),(0.309,0.951),(-0.309,0.951),(-0.809,0.588),(-1.,0.),(-0.809,-0.588),(-0.309,-0.951),(0.309,-0.951),(0.809,-0.588),(1.,0.)}{
        \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
    }

    \weigthgraphfromadj[bend left=10]{p}{{0,5,0,0,1,0,5,0,0,5},{2,0,1,0,0,5,0,2,0,0},{0,5,0,2,0,0,2,0,5,0},{0,0,7,0,5,0,0,2,0,5},{7,0,0,7,0,5,0,0,1,0},{0,5,0,0,2,0,5,0,0,1},{2,0,5,0,0,1,0,5,0,0},{0,7,0,5,0,0,2,0,1,0},{0,0,5,0,7,0,0,5,0,1},{5,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,1,0}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

To handle self-loops a simple if could be used, and proper styling could adjust the settings (even per-node):

```
\newcommand{\graphfromadj}[3][]{
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {#3}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell>0%
                \ifnum\c=\r%
                    \draw[arc/.try=\cell] (#2\r) edge[loop arc/.try=\r] (#2\c);
                \else
                    \draw[arc/.try=\cell, #1] (#2\r) edge (#2\c);
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

Detecting bi-directional edges and drawing them differently is more difficult with this approach.

## Importing from an external file

Here's a possible approach using `catchfile` which assumes the data is in the file `demo.dat`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\graphfromadj}[3][]{
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in #3{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell>0%
                \ifnum\c=\r%
                    \draw[arc/.try=\cell] (#2\r) edge[loop arc/.try=\r] (#2\c);
                \else
                    \draw[arc/.try=\cell, #1] (#2\r) edge (#2\c);
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\CatchFileDef{\mymat}{demo.dat}{\endlinechar=-1 }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=5,
        vertex/.style={draw,circle},
        arc/.style={draw=blue,thick,->},
        arc label/.style={fill=white, font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt},
        loop arc/.style={in=20,out=70,loop,min distance=.8mm}
    ]

    \foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(0.809,0.588),(0.309,0.951),(-0.309,0.951),(-0.809,0.588),(-1.,0.),(-0.809,-0.588),(-0.309,-0.951),(0.309,-0.951),(0.809,-0.588),(1.,0.)}{
        \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
    }

    \graphfromadj[bend left=10]{p}{\mymat}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was my first thought (and almost exactly the same code). But self-loops don't work (although they aren't required by the OPs example) and without considerable extra work it isn't possible to optimise two "uni-directional" edges into a single "bi-directional" edge.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Very good points! However people looking for a solution handling simple cases could find this useful?

Comment: @MarkWibrow I added support for self-loops. bi-directional edges are still treated as two separate edges.

Comment: @Bordaigorl Many thanks! How to import the data of coordinates and adjacency matrix from external files?

Comment: @user25607 it all depends on the constraints on the format of the external file. If you are in control of its contents you can just wrap the adjacency matrix in a `\graphfromadj{p}` call and then `\input` the file from the main `tex` file...

Comment: @Bordaigorl For example, we just put the datas in your example in `vert.tex` and `adj.tex`. I just cannot get it work.

Comment: The simplest thing that comes to mind is using [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14147/36686) to assign the contents of the file to a macro and then use the macro as argument of `\graphfromadj` (this requires removing the brackets around `#3` in the definition of `\graphfromadj`). There might be easier solutions.

Comment: What about showing us what you are trying in a new **question** so I can give you a solution there?

Comment: @Bordaigorl I agree, the simple version is certainly useful. Unfortunately, posters' are rarely satisfied with the simple solution and (as in this question) sequentially (or randomly) update their requirements.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I`m so sorry. `Import the data from external files` is the last requirement and the question will not change any more.

Comment: @user25607 here you are. But let me just say your question was not posed in a very nice way: a snippet with coordinates is not a MWE and links to external files are not encouraged in this site. Please consider these points next time

Comment: @Bordaigorl If I change `\if\cell1%` to `\ifnum\cell>0%`, the last example fails with `\mymat`.

Comment: @user25607 yes, that's a problem. I suspect it has to do with catcodes assigned to numbers by catchfile. I'll open a new question about this since I would be curious to see a solution.

Comment: @user25607 there you go, I corrected the last part of the answer so `\ifnum` works. @egreg explained the problem in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203252/36686)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Consider using `Asymptote` (part of TeXLive distribution),
it is perfectly suited for such tasks. 
Here is a brief `MWE` to draw 
[wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)
with added loop to the node 5.
This code use three main inputs: adjacency matrix `adj`,
a list of coordinates `pair[] vcenter` 
and a list of self-loops directions (in degrees) `real[] SelfLoopDir`.

```
// gmx.asy
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
size(4cm);
import graph;
import fontsize;

defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

pair[] vcenter={
(120,130),
(60,250),
(100,380),
(230,360),
(200,220),
(340,430),
};

typedef int[][]Matrix;

Matrix adj={
{1, 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,},
{1, 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,},
{0, 1,  0,  1,  0,  0,},
{0, 0,  1,  0,  1,  1,},
{1, 1,  0,  1,  1,  0,},
{0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,},
};

real[] SelfLoopDir={-50,0,0,0,124,0};

int n=vcenter.length;

assert(n==adj.length && n==adj[0].length && n==SelfLoopDir.length,"Inconsistent input data. ");

real nodeR=40;
guide nodeShape=scale(nodeR)*unitcircle;

guide loop=(0,0){dir(-60)}..(nodeR*1.8,0)
           ..{dir(180+60)}cycle;

pen edgePen=orange+1bp;
pen nodeFgPen=deepblue+0.8bp;
pen nodeBgPen=lightgreen+0.8bp;

void drawNode(pair c){

  filldraw(shift(c.x,c.y)*nodeShape,nodeBgPen,nodeFgPen);
}

void drawEdge(int i, int j){ 
  pair p=vcenter[i], q=vcenter[j]; 
  if(i==j){
    draw(shift(p.x,p.y)*rotate(SelfLoopDir[i])*loop, edgePen);
  }else {
    draw(p--q, edgePen);
  }
}

void drawEdges(Matrix A){
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<=i;++j){
      if(A[i][j]>0){
        drawEdge(i,j);
      }
    }
  }
};

drawEdges(adj);

for(int i=0;i<vcenter.length;++i){
  drawNode(vcenter[i]);
}

for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
  label("$n_{"+string(i+1)+"}$",vcenter[i]);
}
```

Process this code with `asy gmx.asy`,
it will run `pdflatex` to make all the labels and combine 
them along with the graphics into `gmx.pdf`.

The code can me modified and enhanced in many ways,
for example to read the data from file or to
make a special class to draw the thing.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is just what I want. Could you enhance it as much as possible? This is an excellent answer.

Comment: @user25607: Well, it can be modified _ad infinitum_.
Do you need something specific to start with?

Comment: For example to read the data from file or to make a special class to draw the thing.

Comment: @user25607 It would have really helped the question in general if you had provided a proper MWE that included this input format… there are so many ways the data could be represented

Comment: How to import the data of coordinates and adjacency matrix from external files?

Comment: For example, we just put the datas in your example in vert.tex and adj.tex

Answer (score 8):

This is a [sagetex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/) approach, which gives you access to a computer algebra system, Sage, plus the Python language. There are two ways to use this package: install Sage on your computer and integrate it with LaTeX. Not such a problem in Linux but maybe troublesome with other operating systems. The second way is to sign up for the free [SageMath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects) account which has everything set up for you. All you'll have to do is copy/paste the code below to get up and running. Modifying the code wouldn't be difficult but there's a ton of documentation for Sage/graphs/LaTeX to wade through depending on how particular you are on the output. I've put some key links below.

Your comment (above) indicated you needed the coordinates in order to "plot each point according to its coordinate and then link them according to the adjacency matrix". Using Sage, those coordinates aren't necessary. The [Graph Format section](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html) gives you 6 ways of getting a graph into Sage. I'll use a matrix and for the second graph I'll take advantage of Sage's extensive graph theory knowledge to get the Petersen graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}% to get the URL in the margins
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph,tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
M = Matrix([(-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0), \
(1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0),(0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0), \
(0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0),(0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1), \
(0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0), \
(0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,1,0), \
(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)])
g = Graph(M)
g.set_pos(g.layout_circular())
g.set_latex_options(graphic_size=(4,4), tkz_style = 'Custom',vertex_size = 0.2,    edge_thickness = 0.04, edge_color = 'black',vertex_labels=False)
\end{sagesilent}
The work done in \textbf{sagesilent} is invisible to us. When we're 
ready to view the graph we can insert it as follows:\\
\begin{center}
\sage{g}
\end{center}
Of course, you can alter the size of the figure by adjusting the 
numbers in \verb!graphic_size=(4,4)! to a different dimension. 
Likewise, other parameters can be adjusted above. There is an 
extensive list of plotting options. See the Sage URL:
\begin{verbatim}
http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html
\end{verbatim}
\begin{sagesilent}
from sage.graphs.graph_latex import check_tkz_graph
check_tkz_graph() # random - depends on TeX installation
h = graphs.PetersenGraph()
h.set_latex_options(graphic_size=(4.3,4.3), tkz_style = 'Art',vertex_size = 0.2, edge_thickness = 0.04,vertex_labels=False)
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{center}
\sage{h}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output from Sagemath Cloud:[image]

Notice a several things. First, using the matrix approach, graph g was set using a circular layout, so I didn't need the points you mentioned above. There are of course, other layout settings. Second, you can set latex options for the output. Plot options are mentioned [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html)
Third, [Sage has knowledge of a wide variety of graph structures](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html#sage.graphs.graph_generators.GraphGenerators.TutteCoxeterGraph). To get the well known Petersen graph, all I do is define graph h to be the Petersen graph and Sage handles the placement of vertices by itself. You could have forced a circular layout of Petersen's graph if you were interested in showing a different looking graph which is isomorphic to it. Fourth, notice I specified tkz_style = 'Art' and got graph output which is using the LaTeX package tkz-graph. [Sage has lots of LaTeX support](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_latex.html?highlight=latex#module-sage.graphs.graph_latex).

Using `sagetex` gets us away from a pure LaTeX approach but gives a quick way of efficiently turning out all sorts of graphs. So this approach isn't using the point plotting approach you asked for but hopefully you can see the benefits of using Sage: imagine the extra difficulty you'd have of setting the points for plotting the Petersen graph in the standard representation shown or, in fact, any graph with a lot of vertices. [AskSage](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/) is a place to go if you have questions using Sage.

Regarding your comment for an example where the user specifies the coordinates you can try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}% to get the URL in the margins
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph,tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
M = [[0,1,1,1,1], [1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,0]]
vertices = ['A','B','C','D','E']

N = 5
output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]"

#Create the vertices
for p in range(0,N):
    output += r"\Vertex[x=0,y=0,Lpos=-180]{A}"
    output += r"\Vertex[x=2,y=0,Lpos=-90]{B}"
    output += r"\Vertex[x=2,y=2,Lpos=90]{C}"
    output += r"\Vertex[x=1,y=4,Lpos=-180]{D}"
    output += r"\Vertex[x=5,y=1,Lpos=0]{E}"

#Create the edges
for i in range(0,N):
    for j in range(i,N):
        if M[i][j]==1:
            output += r"\Edge(%s)(%s)"%(vertices[i],vertices[j])
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
If you want to control the positioning, then there is no 
need to work with either a (Sage) matrix or a (Sage) graph structure.
Just specify the position of the vertices along with the 
label position just read throught the top half of the matrix
(since the matrix of every graph is symmetric).
\begin{center}
\sagestr{output}
\end{center}
Sage gives you the flexibility to choose the approach that you
think is best.
\end{document}
```

The output is:[image]

Comment: Thanks! I know something about sage. In fact, I have draw [120-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell) in Sage and Mathematica. But [the former](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i31MDH7) is not as better as [the later](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1mggHNYC). So I want to give the coordinates manually. Sometimes there maybe no existing layouts is what I want.

Comment: I would imagine that the Python which comes with Sage could help with that (like the answer to the question you linked to).

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: OK: Example appended to previous answer. Python looping to figure out which edges are needed.

Comment: Thanks! Though this works on sagemath-cloud, but I can not make it on my local computer. I failed to configure sagetex.

Comment: If you have Sage installed on your computer then you've got to [Make Sagetex Known to TeX](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/installation/sagetex.html). Then you have to go through the [3 step process for compiling](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/sagetex.html). I've had no problems with Linux but have heard of complaints from others. Using Sagemath Cloud makes everything simple.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly not robust for "serious business" and it does not handle self-loops very well (you have to specify a number greater than one that corresponds to a predefined "loop" style - some examples are given). In addition, "edge" styles are provided to customise non-loop edges.

Also it requires `lualatex`. By specifying coordinates using braces rather than parentheses, it is trivial to convert data structures into lua tables.

Also keys are provided to load the require data from files.

Note that the graph drawing library `circular` provides automatic layouts (e.g., `simple necklace layout`) than means that the required circular arrangement of nodes could be drawn without specific coordinates as shown in the second (blue) graph (although note that the nodes are in a different order):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}

\usegdlibrary{circular}
\tikzset{%
  edge 1/.style={>=Stealth},
  loop 1/.style={},
  loop 2/.style={loop above},
  loop 3/.style={loop below},
  loop 4/.style={loop left},
  loop 5/.style={loop right},
} 
\def\luafiletomacro#1#2{%
  \edef#2{%
    \directlua{%
      file = io.open("#1", "r")
      data = file:read("*all")
      file:close()
      tex.print(data)
    }%
  }%
}
\tikzgraphsset{% 
  n/.store in=\n,
  n = 1,
  adjacency matrix/.store in=\tikzadjacencymatrix,
  adjacency matrix from file/.code={\luafiletomacro{#1}{\tikzadjacencymatrix}},
  vertices/.store in=\tikzvertices,
  vertices={},  
  vertices from file/.code={\luafiletomacro{#1}{\tikzvertices}},
  declare={adjacency graph}{[
    /utils/exec={\edef\adjacencygraph{%
      \directlua{%
         local i, j, n, v
         local vertices = {\tikzvertices}
         local matrix = {\tikzadjacencymatrix}
         local graph_spec = ""
         n = 0
         for i, vertex in pairs(vertices) do
            x = vertex[1]
            y = vertex[2]
            n = n + 1
            graph_spec = graph_spec .. " " .. n .. 
              "[at={(" .. x .. "," .. y .. ")}];"
         end
         if n == 0 then
           n = \n\space
           for i = 1,n do
              if i > 1 then
                graph_spec = graph_spec .. ","
              end
              graph_spec = graph_spec .. " " .. i 
           end
         end
         graph_spec = graph_spec .. ";"
         for i = 1,n do
           for j = 1,i do
             v = matrix[i][j]
             if v > 0 then
               if i == j then
                 graph_spec = graph_spec .. " " .. i .. 
                   " ->[/tikz/loop " .. v .. "/.try]" .. i .. "; "
               else
                 if matrix[j][i] == 1 then
                   graph_spec = graph_spec .. " " .. i .. 
                     " <->[/tikz/edge " .. v .. "/.try]" .. j .. "; "
                 else
                   graph_spec = graph_spec .. " " .. i .. 
                     " ->[/tikz/edge " .. v .. "/.try]" .. j .. "; "
                 end
               end
             end
           end
         end
         tex.print(graph_spec)  
      }%    
    }},
    parse/.expand once=\adjacencygraph
  ]}%  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
\graph [nodes={circle, draw}, no placement] {

   adjacency graph[
     vertices={{0.809,0.588},{0.309,0.951},{-0.309,0.951},{-0.809,0.588},
       {-1.,0.},{-0.809,-0.588},{-0.309,-0.951},{0.309,-0.951},
       {0.809,-0.588},{1.,0.}},
     adjacency matrix={%
      {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
      {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
      {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
      {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
      {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
      {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}
     }];
};

\tikzset{shift=(270:2), edge 1/.style={draw=blue}}
\graph [nodes={circle, draw}, simple necklace layout, node distance=1.25cm] {

    adjacency graph[n=10, 
      adjacency matrix={%
       {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
       {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
       {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
       {1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}
      }];
 };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I can not run it in my texlive with lualatex, though I download the needed `pgflibrarygraphdrawing.code.tex` and `tikzlibrarygraphdrawing.code.tex`.

Comment: @user25607 you need _much_ more than those two files. Rather than downloading individual files, it would be easier to upgrade to PGF 3.0 manually or simply to upgrade to the latest texlive release.

Comment: How to import the data of coordinates and adjacency matrix from external files?

Comment: For example, we just put the datas in your example in vert.tex and adj.tex

Comment: @user25607 it is trivial to load the data into a macro as my updated answer shows.

Comment: Thanks very much! `Importing the data from external files` is the last requirement and the question will not change any more.

Comment: Could you kindly show how to import `vertices` from `vertices.tex` and `adjacency matrix` from `adjacency matrix.tex`? I do not see the command in the above example.

Comment: @user25607 instead of using `vertices={...}` simply use `vertices from file={vertices.tex}`. The same applies for the adjacency matrix.