# Automating a graph drawing procedure

Tags: graphs, automation

Here it is: I want to draw a big graph, say 50 vertices and ~200 edges. 
I'm getting the edges from the output of GAP, a programme for computational
algebra. As it is, I have no idea what the graph will look like, but I can ask the programme to print pairs of integers or whatever. For instance:

```
1 -- 2,
1 -- 3,
1 -- 31,
1 -- 32,
1 -- 33,
1 -- 34,
1 -- 35,
1 -- 36,
1 -- 37,
1 -- 38,
1 -- 39,
1 -- 40,
1 -- 41,
1 -- 42,
2 -- 3,
2 -- 31,
2 -- 32,
2 -- 33,
2 -- 34,
2 -- 35,
2 -- 36,
2 -- 37,
2 -- 38,
2 -- 39,
2 -- 40,
2 -- 41,
2 -- 42,
3 -- 31,
3 -- 32,
3 -- 33,
3 -- 34,
3 -- 35,
3 -- 36,
3 -- 37,
3 -- 38,
3 -- 39,
3 -- 40,
3 -- 41,
3 -- 42,
4 -- 6,
4 -- 9,
4 -- 37,
4 -- 38,
4 -- 39,
5 -- 8,
5 -- 11,
5 -- 37,
5 -- 38,
5 -- 39,
6 -- 9,
6 -- 37,
6 -- 38,
6 -- 39,
7 -- 10,
7 -- 12,
7 -- 37,
7 -- 38,
7 -- 39,
8 -- 11,
8 -- 37,
8 -- 38,
8 -- 39,
9 -- 37,
9 -- 38,
9 -- 39,
10 -- 12,
10 -- 37,
10 -- 38,
10 -- 39,
11 -- 37,
11 -- 38,
11 -- 39,
12 -- 37,
12 -- 38,
12 -- 39,
13 -- 15,
13 -- 18,
13 -- 34,
13 -- 35,
13 -- 36,
14 -- 17,
14 -- 20,
14 -- 34,
14 -- 35,
14 -- 36,
15 -- 18,
15 -- 34,
15 -- 35,
15 -- 36,
16 -- 19,
16 -- 21,
16 -- 34,
16 -- 35,
16 -- 36,
17 -- 20,
17 -- 34,
17 -- 35,
17 -- 36,
18 -- 34,
18 -- 35,
18 -- 36,
19 -- 21,
19 -- 34,
19 -- 35,
19 -- 36,
20 -- 34,
20 -- 35,
20 -- 36,
21 -- 34,
21 -- 35,
21 -- 36,
22 -- 24,
22 -- 27,
22 -- 40,
22 -- 41,
22 -- 42,
23 -- 26,
23 -- 29,
23 -- 40,
23 -- 41,
23 -- 42,
24 -- 27,
24 -- 40,
24 -- 41,
24 -- 42,
25 -- 28,
25 -- 30,
25 -- 40,
25 -- 41,
25 -- 42,
26 -- 29,
26 -- 40,
26 -- 41,
26 -- 42,
27 -- 40,
27 -- 41,
27 -- 42,
28 -- 30,
28 -- 40,
28 -- 41,
28 -- 42,
29 -- 40,
29 -- 41,
29 -- 42,
30 -- 40,
30 -- 41,
30 -- 42,
31 -- 32,
31 -- 33,
32 -- 33,
34 -- 35,
34 -- 36,
35 -- 36,
37 -- 38,
37 -- 39,
38 -- 39,
40 -- 41,
40 -- 42,
41 -- 42,
```

and I want to create a graph (in the combinatorial sense) having vertices 1,2,...
and edges drawn according to the pairs printed. Since I'll be getting a huge list,
is there some method that will allow me to automatically enter this list with copy-paste into some code and have the graph drawn for me? I can obviously change what GAP prints, e.g. if instead of 1 2 we need (1,2) or some other string with relevant information.

I have zero knowledge of tikz.

Update: using the code suggested, I get the following graph:

[image]

Any suggestions how to better draw this graph would be welcome (the messy one in the middle is the [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) graph on 6 vertices).

Comment: If you can cook up a small (but still realistic) example dataset we can fiddle with it but this is not a math site so what you mean by graph is not so familiar to (some of) us. Paint drawings are also more than welcome ;)

Comment: The meaning of the word graph is the same as Petersen graph, for instance, although I don't know if mine will end up looking regular like the Petersen graph.

Comment: [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/index.html) includes GAP and has various algorithms for drawing graphs which can be used by [sagetex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/). I have mentioned some of this (drawing Petersen's graph) in my answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202151/how-to-plot-a-graph-from-its-adjacency-matrix-and-coordinates-of-vertices/202252#202252).

Comment: I need time to look carefully at your answer there, but just a quick question: can sage (or sage.tex) automatically deduce from the data what the connected components are and draw them "separately" in some sense (but still as one graph)?

Comment: So we are supposed to know what Petersen graph is then? Is it too difficult what happens to these numbers in terms of the resulting image? You have two columns of data. It can't be that complicated

Comment: Sage can determine whether a graph is [connected](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html) but I don't know if it will automatically  draw the components separately.

Comment: Regarding the Petersen graph, I have no idea whether you are supposed to know what it is, but you are supposed to look it up if the term "graph" I used is not clear. In case your argument is that I should have provided a link to save time, I simply don't know how to do that,

Comment: Finding a good (i.e. useful for humans) visual representation of a large unknown graph is a hard problem. You might want to consider using a visualization tool as a preliminary step, so you have an idea of what you want. Perhaps gephi (http://gephi.github.io/) or something like it. (I don't know that particular one - just found it with google.)

Comment: I guess one can always put the vertices on a circle in a regular polygon configuration and draw the edges to obtain the graph as a subgraph of K_n. Here, however, the problem is simple. One needs only draw K_6 in the centre and just one "branch", then put the other two by rotation.

Comment: The merit of the approach exhibited in the answer (and the reason for my original question) is that with zero effort you get a first idea what a good visualisation of the graph might be. Imagine trying to do this by hand...

Comment: Seen the update. Can you use the PGF/OGDF interface? The algorithm SpringEmbedderKK may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}

\begin{document}
\tikz [rounded corners]
\graph [spring layout, node distance=2cm]
{
1 -- 2,
1 -- 3,
1 -- 31,
1 -- 32,
1 -- 33,
2 -- 3,
32 -- 33,
33 -- 31
};

\end{document}
```

Needs to be compiled with LuaLaTeX. More details on PGF manual, page 369 and 421.

[image]

Comment: Cheers. So I should ask that the output be printed in the form a -- b,

Comment: My tex editor (latexian) says "I can't find file tikzlibrarygraphdrawing. Is this common?

Comment: Are you using TeXlive or MikTeX?

Comment: I am using TeXlive.

Comment: On my system compiles fine... but I'm using the latest TeXlive. Try to update.

Comment: @StefanosAivazidis: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)