# Gephi Graphs in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to create Gephi Graphs with latex? See
[Graph1](https://gephi.org/images/screenshots/layout2.png)
[Graph2](https://gephi.org/images/screenshots/layout1.png)

[image]

[image]

Asking this question just out of curiosity. 
I'd like to add that Gephi is not simply connecting dots.

Comment: I would try paint and canvas from a distance of about 6 feet.  Just kidding.  Welcome to the site.  I wish you the best.

Comment: [Computing a visually pleasing (or useful) graph layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing) is not a trivial task.  It is also computationally intensive.  LaTeX is absolutely not suitable for such tasks.  Maybe if you already have the coordinates precomputed, then the drawing can be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating a graph drawing procedure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228709/automating-a-graph-drawing-procedure)

Comment: Maybe I was wrong.  There seem to be packages for small graphs.  For large ones like in your pictures you should really use dedicated software.

Comment: doesn't Gephi already have a tikz plugin? [here](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/tikzexport/)?

Comment: I think it is possible to compile such a graph in LaTeX using the TikZ `graphdrawing` library.  Though, I don't think it is sensible because it will probably take forever to typeset.  Better use dedicated software and include the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create your export file from your Gephi graph using TikzExport, then

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\input{Gephiit.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is TikzExport and how can I get it? doesn't seem to be a plugin for Gephi